# Is there a way to make this type of query work?

Tags: google-sheets, function-query

=query(G2:I80,"select G,H,I where H=max(H) group by I",-1)

Columnn G is names
Column H is vote count and 
Column I is Their respective teams.

I want to view the top voted names of each team and sometimes the some top voted names are tied so I wanna view both names using the query above but it dont seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want (a formula that does not work is not a good guide) but perhaps:

```
=sort(filter(query(G2:I80,"select G, H, I ",-1),H2:H80=Max(H:H)),3,TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks but doesnt work to my requirement. I posted another question to ask it better. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715665/query-to-view-only-top-counts-and-counted-by-group)