# Query to View only top counts and counted by group

Tags: google-sheets, function-query

I wanted to use this query
=query(G2:I80,"select G,H,I where H=max(H) group by I",-1)

---

From this:

Cdd Cts T

NWH   4     A1

LBB     3       A1

MP      3       A1

DC      2       A1

AK      10      A10

CC  3       A10

SC      2       A11

JL      1       A11

VT      1       A11

---

To This:

T   Cdd  Cts

A1      NWH  4

A10     AK   10

A11     SC   2

---

Am I doing it right? Or I have to come up with something to manually count them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(I2:I), sort({I2:I, G2:H},3,), {1,2,3},0)))
```

and see if that works for you ?

How does it work:

1: with sort() a new 'virtual' table is created with col I as the first column. That new table is sorted on col H (latest dates appear on top).
2: a list with the unique values is retrieved from col I (with the unique function)
3: that list is 'looked up' (with vlookup). When a match is found it retrieves the first 3 columns ({1, 2, 3} or: col I, G and H). Vlookup only returns the first match found: since our list is sorted, that will be the entry with the latest date.
4: if nothing is found an error is suppressed with the iferror().

Comment: But I have no idea what is going on in the formula. Haha.

Comment: Hi Pang, I added a brief explanation to my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to lookup the top 2 voted ones in that team say if the top voted candidates are tied with equal number of votes? How do I work around from that?